# How to submit a form using simple_form_for when what's being submitted isn't part of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to submit a form that contains fields for both an event and an invitation to that event. Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :start_at %>
    <%= f.input :end_at %>
    <%= f.input :all_day %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :owner_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <% if false %>
    <%= f.association :sitter, label_method: lambda { |s| "#{s.name}" }, collection: User.all %>
    <%= f.association :group, label_method: lambda { |g| "#{g.group_name}" }, collection: Group.where(:owner_id => current_user.id) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :user_emails, as: :text %>
    <%= form_tag event_invitations_path, :method => :post do %>_tag :user_emails %>
  </div><div>
    <%= label_tag "Your message:" %>
  </div><div>
    <%= text_area_tag :email_message %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</br>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary'   %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is (perhaps obviously) not working. `:user_emails` is NOT part of the event or invitation model as it's a list of emails that will be used to create invitations. Basically I merged two forms, one that was accepting the email/send invitation piece and one that was accepting the event information. I think I have my controller and model set up properly to take care of this but how do i submit this information as part of the same form without getting an "undefined_method" error (since user_emails doesn't belong to events). Let me know if you want to see my model/controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

```
<%= label_tag "User", "Email"%>
<%= text_area_tag "user_emails", "example@example.com"%>
```

See the documentation for more options on [text_area_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag) and [label_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag)